# Why is my program not considering adding up the value that the user inputs.?

Tags: java, for-loop

I am trying to make a program, that gets an integer from the user.
Adds up all the numbers from 1 to that number, and display the total. Below is the program that I wrote and the problem is sum doesn't add the value the user inputs.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AddingValuesForLoop
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int Number,Sum;
        Sum=0;
        Scanner keyboard=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your Number: ");
        Number=keyboard.nextInt();
        for (int i=1;i<=Number;i++) 
        {
            Sum=i+Number;
            System.out.println("\r"+i+"");
        }
        System.out.println("the total Sum = "+Sum+".");
    }
}
```

> OUTPUT:
>
> Enter number: 5
>
> 1
>
> 2
>
> 3
>
> 4
>
> 5
>
> The total Sum = 10.

Comment: Try printing out `Sum` in your loop to see if it has the values it's supposed to have.  (Also, in Java, variable names should begin with a lower-case letter, like `sum` instead of `Sum`.)

Comment: And definitely don't shadow (re-use) names in the java.lang package, like [`Number`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html). It can lead to all sorts of confusions. (I'd stay away from shadowing names in other common packages, too, like java.util or java.io).

Comment: If all you're doing is summing up the value of each iteration value leading up to the supplied number then just use: `sum+= i;` or the long way: `sum = sum + i;` Don't bother trying to add the supplied integer value (in **Number**) in each iteration. So if a value of **5** is supplied then the sum would end up being **15**. Unless of course I read your post incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in this line:

```
Sum=i+Number;
```

This line means that your sum will contain the last i value from the loop and the number entered by the user, it should looks like:

```
Sum += i;
```

And then add the number entered by the user to the Sum value, your code will looks like that:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AddingValuesForLoop{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int Number,Sum;
        Sum=0;
        Scanner keyboard=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your Number: ");
        Number=keyboard.nextInt();
        for (int i=1;i<=Number;i++) {
            Sum +=i;
            System.out.println("\r"+i+"");
        }
        Sum+=Number;
        System.out.println("the total Sum = "+Sum+".");
    }
}
```

Comment: Just tell me why?

Comment: Try it and see.

Comment: OK, but please fix the `Sum += Sum` mistake.

Answer (score 1):

You shall write Sum = i + Sum instead of Sum=i+Number. Here is the full code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AddingValuesForLoop{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int Number,Sum;
        Sum=0;
        Scanner keyboard=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your Number: ");
        Number=keyboard.nextInt();
        for (int i=1;i<=Number;i++) {
            // Add i to sum until now
            Sum=Sum+i;
        }
        System.out.println("the total Sum = "+Sum+".");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

2 problems with your program.

Firstly, you are resetting the value of Sum in each iteration. So during the last iteration, the i value is 5, Number value is 5 and thus you get output as 10.

Secondly, you want to add up numbers from 1 to that Number, so it should be something like this:
sum = sum + i;
If the user enters 3
(sum = 0 + 1, sum = 1 + 2, sum = 3 + 3), thus output will be 6.

Answer (score -1):

since you use

```
Sum=i+Number;
```

which in that code means get the value of i and value of number and sum them together and put it in Sum var each time that's way there is no sum happening 
you should use

```
Sum += i+Number;
```

which means 
Sum = Sum + (i+Number);